# What is the rule for the usage of parenthesis in method invocation?

Tags: ruby

In invocation of a method, I could not omit the parenthesis in the following case:

```
t=[]
t.push {}
# => []  # I expected [{}]
t.push({})
# => [{}]
```

What rules should I apply to avoid this?

Comment: `{}` is interpreted as a block, like `t.each { ... }`

Comment: @Stefan, why isn't an exception raised, considering that `push` doesn't take a block?

Comment: @CarySwoveland you can pass a block to any method. The method itself *could* raise an exception e.g. `raise ArgumentError 'does not take a block' if block_given?` but I've never seen this.

Comment: @Stefan, yes, of course; though `push` is a built-in here, Ruby doesn't know if we've modified it to take a block. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you pass `{}` as the only argument (so there are no commas in the call), Ruby can not tell if you mean an empty hash or empty block, so you need to use parentheses to distinguish it:

```
t.push(){}
t.push({})
```

In other cases, good rule of thumb is that parentheses are needed if you use method call as argument directly i.e.

```
method arg0, arg1, other_method(arg01, arg02), arg2, arg3
```

When your method call gets even more nested, it is probably better to sparete method calls using local variables (or rethink your interfaces), i.e.

```
arg3 = other_method arg01, arg02
methods arg0, arg1, arg3, arg3, arg4
```

Comment: I always add parentheses if I split parameters over multiple lines.

Comment: @ReggieB I didn't meant splitting parameters over multiple lines, I'll clarify. I also rarely see anyone doing it, Ruby is fine withouthem and many Rubyists tend to avoid unnecessary syntactic noise. Not that it'a a bad thing though.

Comment: OK - and I realise it's a style choice. I thought it was a point worth making considering the title of this question, but only in a comment.

Comment: You may want want to add something about the use of parentheses when using the ternary operator.

Comment: While Ruby supports not using parentheses on method calls, a lot of us grumpy old developers almost always use them, rather than allow the interpreter to get it wrong. A pair of wrapping parentheses do not add enough visual noise to cause problems but they can make a big difference in code reliability and ease debugging and maintenance. You'll find a lot of questions on SO where the root cause of the problem triggering the question is the lack of the parentheses so they are recommended in spite of the noise.

Answer (score 2):

You can switch to `<<` from `push` to avoid this pitfall

```
t = []
t << {}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you writer like this:

```
t.push {}
```

Ruby will translate to this:

```
t.push() {}
```

`push` method without arguments and with block